# I have a code error in Android Studio .class identifier expected how do i solve this?

Tags: java, android-studio

i have an error in Android Studio .class identifier expected. how do i solve this?[.class Identifier expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH2Kr.png)

Comment: Please add the code where this error happens.

Comment: public void openChaptersActivity () {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, openChaptersActivity().class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

Comment: Adding the code with more context to the question and not as a comment would make it easier for others to help you. For example from your code snippet it is not possible to say what `this` actually is. Also try to format your code and question.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given only guessing is possible:

Replace

```
openChaptersActivity().class
```

with

```
ChaptersActivity.class
```

so that it looks like

```
public void openChaptersActivity () { 
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChaptersActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent); 
}
```